# Find First of Each Foreach Loop Pass

Tags: php, foreach, count

I'm trying to build a keyword search function that is dynamic so it is getting the column names passed into it as an array generated from a query along with the keywords from the form post. It works well for Any Keywords and For Exact Phrase (each using a different set of programming not shown here) but the part that needs to fetch All Keywords is giving me some problems. Basically I need to know when it has completed the first pass through the fields for the first keyword so that it can add an AND to the WHERE clause before it continues to the next pass for however many keywords there are.

I tried below to make it switch over to AND by using the percentage of values but can'y quite work out the math so need some assistance. For this test, there are 9 columns and only two keywords but either could vary.

```
// Fetch the keywords
$keyword = (isset($_POST['s_keyword'])) ? $_POST['s_keyword'] : "";

// Subtract one because ID column is not being used
$len = ((count(array_keys($queryField))-1) * count($keywords));

// Count basic fields to check, subtract one since ID is not being used
$lenbase = (count(array_keys($queryField))-1);
$i = - (count($keywords)); // Subtract number of keywords
foreach ($keywords as $keyword) :
    $keyword = str_replace("'", "''", trim($keyword));
    foreach (array_keys($queryField) as $column) :
        $i++;
        if ($column === 'ID') continue;
        if (strlen($Where) == 0) $Where .= " WHERE (";
        if ($len %$lenbase != 0) $Where .= "(`$column` LIKE '%" . $keyword . "%') AND ";
        if ($i != $len) $Where .= "(`$column` LIKE '%" . $keyword . "%') OR ";
        if ($i == $len) $Where .= "(`$column` LIKE '%" . $keyword . "%') ";
    endforeach;
endforeach;
```

it is retrieving the keywords from a form post

```
$keyword = (isset($_POST['s_keyword'])) ? $_POST['s_keyword'] : "";
$keywords = explode(" ", trim($keyword));
```

Without the ***if ($len %$lenbase != 0)*** etc conditional, it is giving this which fetches any keyword but not all (a space was added for clarity):

```
WHERE ((`StorageArea` LIKE '%Paso%') 
OR (`Size` LIKE '%Paso%') 
OR (`Winery` LIKE '%Paso%') 
OR (`Brand` LIKE '%Paso%') 
OR (`Appellation` LIKE '%Paso%') 
OR (`ReleaseYear` LIKE '%Paso%') 
OR (`Varietal` LIKE '%Paso%') 
OR (`Status` LIKE '%Paso%') 
OR (`CountryName` LIKE '%Paso%') 

OR (`StorageArea` LIKE '%Robles%') 
OR (`Size` LIKE '%Robles%') 
OR (`Winery` LIKE '%Robles%') 
OR (`Brand` LIKE '%Robles%') 
OR (`Appellation` LIKE '%Robles%') 
OR (`ReleaseYear` LIKE '%Robles%') 
OR (`Varietal` LIKE '%Robles%') 
OR (`Status` LIKE '%Robles%')
OR (`CountryName` LIKE '%Robles%'))
```

but I am looking for this:

```
WHERE ((`StorageArea` LIKE '%Paso%') 
OR (`Size` LIKE '%Paso%') 
OR (`Winery` LIKE '%Paso%') 
OR (`Brand` LIKE '%Paso%') 
OR (`Appellation` LIKE '%Paso%') 
OR (`ReleaseYear` LIKE '%Paso%') 
OR (`Varietal` LIKE '%Paso%') 
OR (`Status` LIKE '%Paso%') 
OR (`CountryName` LIKE '%Paso%') 

AND (`StorageArea` LIKE '%Robles%') 
OR (`Size` LIKE '%Robles%') 
OR (`Winery` LIKE '%Robles%') 
OR (`Brand` LIKE '%Robles%') 
OR (`Appellation` LIKE '%Robles%') 
OR (`ReleaseYear` LIKE '%Robles%') 
OR (`Varietal` LIKE '%Robles%') 
OR (`Status` LIKE '%Robles%') 
OR (`CountryName` LIKE '%Robles%'))
```

The input $queryField is an array that is generated dynamically from a query and after stripping it down to the keys, in this case it looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => ID
    [1] => StorageArea
    [2] => Size
    [3] => Winery
    [4] => Brand
    [5] => Appellation
    [6] => ReleaseYear
    [7] => Varietal
    [8] => Status
    [9] => CountryName
)
```

Comment: Please provide a clear input that should lead to that output. Also what is `$len`?

Comment: Sorry, $len is from an earlier portion of the function so I forgot to apply it to the question and have just done so. It simply says how many fields there are. As stated, the input is an array of column/alias names from a query and $s_keyword is from a form post. The current and expected output were posted with the question.

Comment: Update your question with sample data showing the array structure you are working with. We dont need to see how you are getting it, just the structured data and the code you are using to process it.

Comment: Sorry again, I'm on the road right now so have access to only my code but not a way to run it. I'll post when I can. However, I made a guess of how the posts were fetched that should be what was used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply make use of [`array_map`](http://www.php.net/array_map) and [`implode`](http://www.php.net/implode):

```
$keywords = ['Paso', 'Robles'];
$columns = ['ID', 'StorageArea', 'Size', 'Winery', 'Brand', 'Appellation', 'ReleaseYear', 'Varietal', 'Status', 'CountryName'];

$where = 'WHERE ' . implode(' AND ', array_map(function ($keyword) use ($columns) {
  $keyword = str_replace("'", "''", $keyword);

  return '(' . implode(' OR ', array_map(function ($column) use ($keyword) {
    return "`$column` LIKE '%$keyword%'";
  }, array_filter($columns, function ($column) {
    return $column !== 'ID';
  }))) . ')';
}, $keywords));
```

Basically:

- the inner `array_map` returns an array with all subconditions for a given keyword, after using `array_filter` to filter out the `ID` column,
- the inner `implode` joins them with `OR`,
- the outer `array_map` returns an array of all these joined `OR`s (one per keyword), after surrounding them with parehtneses,
- finally the outer `implode` joins those with `AND`, creating the final clause.

So, in other words, we go from:

1. `[
     <column1> LIKE '%<keyword1>%', 
     <column2> LIKE '%<keyword1>%, 
     ...
    ]` (inner `array_map`'s array result)
2. `<column1> LIKE '%<keyword1>% 
    OR <column2> LIKE '%<keyword1>% 
    OR ...` (inner `join`'s string result)
3. `[
     (<column1> LIKE '%<keyword1>% OR <column2> LIKE '%<keyword1>% OR...), 
     (<column1> LIKE '%<keyword2>% OR <column2> LIKE '%<keyword2>% OR...), ...
   ]` (outer `array_map`'s array result)
4. `(<column1> LIKE '%<keyword1>% OR <column2> LIKE '%<keyword1>% OR...)
    AND (<column1> LIKE '%<keyword2>% OR <column2> LIKE '%<keyword2>% OR...)
    AND ...` (outer `join`'s string result).

**Demo: https://3v4l.org/GqEXQ** (with added `\n` chars to produce a clearer output)

Comment: Even if it works, these approach sacrifices from readability and simplicity a lot. Nested callbacks increasing the complexity a lot and debugging any problem here in the future may be pretty time consuming. I would ask first; do I really need to do this kind of search on database? Seems like every product has lot of attributes. I would index these product data on a platform which has a strong full-text search capabilities such as Elastic or Apache Solr then start searching the keywords there rather than on database.

Comment: @edigu There is nothing complex about this code really, if you understand how these (relatively basic) PHP functions work. Building arrays and `implode`ing them is definitely the way to go here anyway (you could easily have simple loops instead of `array_map` if you're not comfortable with that though). As for your other question (which I find relevant), it should probably rather be directed at OP's question itself.

Comment: @Jeto Thank you! It's nothing like the code I had and different than anything else on any of my sites to the point that I don't understand how it works. However, it does but without a foreach loop, I'm not sure how to filter out the ID column and it is creating a WHERE clause that includes it. With ID being included, there is an ambiguity error and it is not a field needed for keyword searching.

Comment: @DonP Right, I forgot about that blacklisted column, see my updated answer with the use of `array_filter`. Also added some more explanation, you should try to understand how that works to be able to maintain it in the future. Let me know if you have questions about it.

Comment: @Jeto Wonderful, thank you! Thank you also for the great explanation that nicely outlines how it works. I've been a programmer for over twenty years but in all honest have not needed to use arrays all that often so not very well-versed in them. To put some consistency in my function that has two other areas that generate queries (this one for ALL keywords, another for ANY keywords and the third for Exact Phrase), I was able to get the ANY keywords part working by simply replacing the AND with OR which was probably not the most elegant way but it worked. Exact Phrase will need some thought.

Comment: You're welcome. Make sure to accept this answer if it helped you fix your issue. You can always make another question so that people can help you adapt this code to handle your other use cases (ANY / exact). Good luck!

Comment: Yes, just accepted it before I saw your comment and I also managed to get the other bits working. Thank you again, it is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I believe given the limited information as to the data structure that you should be putting your and part of the code immediately before the outer foreach closes. you will need to check that the loop has not finished because if it has you will need to omit the and and close the sql statement (I presume that's what it is).

```
foreach($arrayvalue as $array):
    foreach($array as $arr):
      // where where where
    endforeach;

    // and or close it here.
    if ($i !== $len) {
       // apply and
    } else {
       // apply closing data
    }

endforeach;
```